# Trying to solve a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve this ODE, but I'm noy sure if I'm doing right:

*Solve $(1-xy)\,dx + x(y-x)\,dy = 0$*

This equation is not exact, so we calculate its integrating factor

$$ \mu = e^{\int\,\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}\,dx} = e^{-x} $$

Then I multiply the ODE to this factor, and I get

$$ e^{-x}(1-xy)\,dx+xe^{-x}(y-x)\,dy = 0 $$

To solve this equation, there must exist a function $f$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = M$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = N$. So, what I did was

$$ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = xe^{-x}(y-x) \hspace{8mm} \Rightarrow \hspace{8mm} f(x,y) = \dfrac{xy^2e^{-x}}{2}-x^2ye^{-x}+g(x) $$

Derivating $f$ with respect to $x$, I got

$$ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{y^2e^{-x}}{2}-2xye^{-x}+g'(x) = e^{-x}(1-xy) $$

I'm not gonna write the expression I found because I would take all night, so, I'm not sure if I'm doing right. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the integrand in your integrating factor evaluates to $-\frac1{x}$, so the integrating factor is:
$$
e^{\int - \frac{dx}{x}} = e^{-\ln x} = \frac1{x}
$$
plugging this in gives $g'=\frac1{x}$

Comment: Right!! I missed the $x$, that's the reason I couldn't solve it. Thanks man!!

Comment: i'm pretty well an expert at making those kind of mistakes!

Comment: I'm sure of that, man.